# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local Machine in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Windows 10 (64 bit) with Microsft office 2013.(64 bit) 
I am seeing this error while trying to run my project. I have also installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 64 bit and Microsoft Access Runtime 2013 but it's still not working.
Please Help me
And thanks in advance

Comment: Please install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable from this link, https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Oh man, I told you that i have installed but it's still not working. Please tell some other solution

Comment: Sorry I meant to say Reinstall. I am thinking that something might have gone wrong in the installation. If it is so, you might be lucky on the second time.

Comment: bro, I re installed but all in vain. I tried to change the configuration to X64, previously it was X86. Now the provider error has been disappeared and a new error of not found database at the given path is shown.

Comment: Even the database is present there.
The connection string i m using is: "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=" + Application.StartupPath + "/pointsale.accdb"